# Doxygen and definitions from makefile

Tags: doxygen

I'm using Doxygen to generate documentation for some code. I have a large makefile with a lot of `OPT+=-DSOME_OPTION` that I want to Doxygen to take into account when it analyses the code, since parts of the code are conditionally compiled.

I know there is a an option `PREDEFINED` in the Doxygen configuration file that specifies macro names that are defined for the preprocessor, but I do not want to manually update this list every time a change happens in the makefile. In essence I want to set the `PREDEFINED` option to scan the makefile for compilation definitions and be automatically updated.

Is this possible with Doxygen?

Comment: If you generate your documentation using make you could define a rule which uses sed, for example, to replace the `PREDEFINED` lines in your doxygen configuration file with your `OPT` flags.